# In Visual Studio 2022 how to make the debug console run inside VS and not in a cmd?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Debugging a console app will run it in cmd , I want it to run inside windows inside VS 2022.

There is similar thread on here but it seems in VS 2022 it is changed or not implemented yet. In project's debug settings the mentioned setting is missing...

There is also Debugging options in Tools/Options but I dont see setting there for this..

googling and checking optioons tried